# Linq to sql - left outer Join

Tags: linq-to-sql

hI..!

```
Dim query = From c In cntxtNorthWind.Customers _
Join x In cntxtNorthWind.Orders On c.CustomerID Equals x.CustomerID into sr _
from b in sr.DefaultifEmpty() _
Select c.CustomerID, x.OrderID, x.ShipAddress
```

Above Outer Left Join cannot execute it's says ***"End of Statament Expected"***

Answer (score 0):

You need to select an object. Easiest way to return an anonymous object. (Not sure how to type in VB.net but i c# it's):

```
...
select new { c.CustomerID, x.OrderID, x.ShipAddress };
```

Believe it's like this i VB.net:

```
...
select New With { c.CustomerID, x.OrderID, x.ShipAddress }
```

Comment: any way I used This below code it's work fine

   Dim query = From c In cntxtNorthWind.Customers _
                     Group Join x In cntxtNorthWind.Orders On c.CustomerID Equals x.CustomerID Into xs = Group _
                    From x In xs.DefaultIfEmpty() _
                    Select c.CustomerID, x.OrderID, x.EmployeeID